# How can you access a link function scope value in Jasmine test spec?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm unit testing an Angular directive via the link function. By compiling the directive as
suggested here -  http://brilliantbritz.com/2015/02/04/getting-the-isolate-scope-of-a-directive/

The first set of tests are running fine and 
I have access to the element.scope() object, i.e, isolatedScope of the directive.

But when running the below test to get the `scope.welcomeMessage` value from the link function.
it returns undefined:

```
it("should contain a welcomeMessage scope value", function() {
    console.log(element.scope()); //value present in scope object
    expect(element.scope().welcomeMessage).toBe("Hello World!"); //undefined
  });
```

I debugged this issue by logging the element.scope() value which does contain the `welcomeMessage`.

Question:

How can you access a link function scope value in Jasmine test spec?

*my-app.spec.js*

```
 describe("my-app", function() {
  var $scope, $compile, element;

  beforeEach(function(){
    //register module and mock dependency
    angular.mock.module("my-app");

  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$compile_) {

    $scope = $rootScope.$new(), //create instance of rootScope
    $compile = _$compile_; // compile attaches directives to HTML template
    element = $compile("<my-app></my-app>")($scope);
    $scope.$digest(); //loop through DOM watchers, check values and trigger listeners
  }));

  it("should contain a defined scope", function() {
    expect(element.scope()).toBeDefined(); //true
  });

  it("should contain a welcomeMessage scope value", function() {
    console.log(element.scope());
    expect(element.scope().welcomeMessage).toBe("Hello World!"); //undefined
  });

});
```

*Log value of element.scope()*

```
LOG LOG: Scope{$$childTail: Scope{$id: 12, $$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$prevSibling: null, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: 
[..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ...], $parent: Scope{$$childTail: ..., $$childHead: ..., 
$$nextSibling: ..., $$watchers: ..., $$listeners: ..., $$listenerCount: ..., $$watchersCount: ..., $id: ..., $$ChildScope: ..., $parent: ..., $$prevSibling: ...}, 
$$phase: null, $root: Scope{$id: ..., $$childTail: ..., $$childHead: ..., $$prevSibling: ..., $$nextSibling: ..., $$watchers: ..., $parent: ..., $$phase: ..., 
$root: ..., $$destroyed: ..., $$listeners: ..., $$listenerCount: ..., $$watchersCount: ..., $$isolateBindings: ..., $$asyncQueue: ..., $$postDigestQueue: ..., 
$$applyAsyncQueue: ..., $$ChildScope: ...}, $$destroyed: false, $$listeners: Object{$destroy: ...}, $$listenerCount: Object{$destroy: ...}, $$watchersCount: 21, 
$$isolateBindings: Object{}, welcomeMessage: 'Hello World!'}, $$childHead: Scope{$id: 12, $$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$prevSibling: null, $$nextSibling: null,
```

*gist of directive*

```
(function() {

  var component = {
    id: "my-app",
    name: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "my-app/my-app.html"
  };

  component.ui = angular.module("my-app");
  component.ui.directive("myApp", fizzComponent);

  function fizzComponent() {

    function fizzContainer(scope, element, params) {

      scope.welcomeMessage = "Hello World!";  
    }
    return {
      scope: {},
      replace: true,
      link: fizzContainer,
      templateUrl: component.templateUrl
    };
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isolated scope property is retrieved with `element.isolateScope().welcomeMessage`, not `element.scope().welcomeMessage`.

Another problem that can doesn't affect anything here but can have consequences is `$scope.$digest()`. It should be either `$scope.$apply()` or `$rootScope.$digest()`.